# Как уменьшить ошибку интерполяции на границах интервала

Tags: c++, математика, численные-методы, интерполяция, полином

Необходимо выполнить интерполяцию данных кубическим сплайном. Все вроде хорошо, но полиномы на концах имеют уж слишком большую ошибку. Что в таком случае обычно делают? 
Пример интерполяции синуса и экспоненты моей программой.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

class knot {
public:
    double x, f, f2;
    void Add(double arg, double func, double func2)
    {
        x = arg;
        f = func;
        f2 = func2;
    }
    knot() {}
};

class vector {
public:
    double* x;
    void Add(int m)
    {
        x = new double[m];
    }
    vector()
    {
    }
};

knot* KnotArray;
int n; // количество узлов интерполяции
double** Coef;
double* b;

//*************************************************************************/
//Решение системы уравнений с трехдиагональной матрицей
//*************************************************************************/
void SolveTriDiag(double** TDM, double* F)
{
    double* alph = new double[n - 1];
    double* beta = new double[n - 1];

    int i;

    alph[0] = -TDM[2][0] / TDM[1][0];
    beta[0] = F[0] / TDM[1][0];

    for (i = 1; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        alph[i] = -TDM[2][i] / (TDM[1][i] + TDM[0][i] * alph[i - 1]);
        beta[i] = (F[i] - TDM[0][i] * beta[i - 1]) / (TDM[1][i] + TDM[0][i] * alph[i - 1]);
    }
    b[n - 1] = (F[n - 1] - TDM[0][n - 1] * beta[n - 2]) / (TDM[1][n - 1] + TDM[0][n - 1] * alph[n - 2]);

    for (i = n - 2; i > -1; i--)
    {
        b[i] = b[i + 1] * alph[i] + beta[i];
    }
}

//*************************************************************************/
//Построение таблицы коэффициентов кубического сплайна  y=f(x)
//*************************************************************************/
int BuildSpline()
{
    double* a = new double[n - 1];
    double* c = new double[n - 1];
    double* d = new double[n - 1];
    double* delta = new double[n - 1];
    double* h = new double[n - 1];
    double** TriDiagMatrix = new double* [3];

    b = new double[n];

    TriDiagMatrix[0] = new double[n];
    TriDiagMatrix[1] = new double[n];
    TriDiagMatrix[2] = new double[n];

    double* f = new double[n];
    double x3, xn;
    int i;

    if (n < 3)
        return -1;

    x3 = KnotArray[2].x - KnotArray[0].x;
    xn = KnotArray[n - 1].x - KnotArray[n - 3].x;

    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        a[i] = KnotArray[i].f;
        h[i] = KnotArray[i + 1].x - KnotArray[i].x;
        delta[i] = (KnotArray[i + 1].f - KnotArray[i].f) / h[i];
        TriDiagMatrix[0][i] = i > 0 ? h[i] : x3;
        f[i] = i > 0 ? 3 * (h[i] * delta[i - 1] + h[i - 1] * delta[i]) : 0;
    }
    TriDiagMatrix[1][0] = h[0];
    TriDiagMatrix[2][0] = h[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        TriDiagMatrix[1][i] = 2 * (h[i] + h[i - 1]);
        TriDiagMatrix[2][i] = h[i];
    }
    TriDiagMatrix[1][n - 1] = h[n - 2];
    TriDiagMatrix[2][n - 1] = xn;
    TriDiagMatrix[0][n - 1] = h[n - 2];


    i = n - 1;
    f[0] = ((h[0] + 2 * x3) * h[1] * delta[0] + powf(h[0], 2) * delta[1]) / x3;
    f[n - 1] = (powf(h[i - 1], 2) * delta[i - 2] + (2 * xn + h[i - 1]) * h[i - 2] * delta[i - 1]) / xn;

    SolveTriDiag(TriDiagMatrix, f);

    /*Coef = new double* [4];
    Coef[0] = new double[n - 1];
    Coef[1] = new double[n - 1];
    Coef[2] = new double[n - 1];
    Coef[3] = new double[n - 1];
    */
    Coef = new double* [n - 1];
    for (int count = 0; count < n - 1; count++)
        Coef[count] = new double[4];
    int j;

    for (j = 0; j < n - 1; j++)
    {
        d[j] = (b[j + 1] + b[j] - 2 * delta[j]) / (h[j] * h[j]);
        c[j] = 2 * (delta[j] - b[j]) / h[j] - (b[j + 1] - delta[j]) / h[j];

        Coef[j][0] = a[j];
        Coef[j][1] = b[j];
        Coef[j][2] = c[j];
        Coef[j][3] = d[j];
    }
    /*for (j = 0; j < n - 1; j++)//вывод значений коэффициентов полиномов
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            printf("%lf\t", Coef[j][i]);
        printf("\n");
    }*/
    return 1;
}
/*************************************************************************/
//Построение таблицы коэффициентов кубического сплайна z=f(x)
//*************************************************************************/
int BuildSpline_z()
{
    double* a = new double[n - 1];
    double* c = new double[n - 1];
    double* d = new double[n - 1];
    double* delta = new double[n - 1];
    double* h = new double[n - 1];
    double** TriDiagMatrix = new double* [3];

    b = new double[n];

    TriDiagMatrix[0] = new double[n];
    TriDiagMatrix[1] = new double[n];
    TriDiagMatrix[2] = new double[n];

    double* f = new double[n];
    double x3, xn;
    int i;

    if (n < 3)
        return -1;

    x3 = KnotArray[2].x - KnotArray[0].x;
    xn = KnotArray[n - 1].x - KnotArray[n - 3].x;

    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        a[i] = KnotArray[i].f2;
        h[i] = KnotArray[i + 1].x - KnotArray[i].x;
        delta[i] = (KnotArray[i + 1].f2 - KnotArray[i].f2) / h[i];
        TriDiagMatrix[0][i] = i > 0 ? h[i] : x3;
        f[i] = i > 0 ? 3 * (h[i] * delta[i - 1] + h[i - 1] * delta[i]) : 0;
    }
    TriDiagMatrix[1][0] = h[0];
    TriDiagMatrix[2][0] = h[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        TriDiagMatrix[1][i] = 2 * (h[i] + h[i - 1]);
        TriDiagMatrix[2][i] = h[i];
    }
    TriDiagMatrix[1][n - 1] = h[n - 2];
    TriDiagMatrix[2][n - 1] = xn;
    TriDiagMatrix[0][n - 1] = h[n - 2];


    i = n - 1;
    f[0] = ((h[0] + 2 * x3) * h[1] * delta[0] + powf(h[0], 2) * delta[1]) / x3;
    f[n - 1] = (powf(h[i - 1], 2) * delta[i - 2] + (2 * xn + h[i - 1]) * h[i - 2] * delta[i - 1]) / xn;

    SolveTriDiag(TriDiagMatrix, f);

    /*Coef = new double* [4];
    Coef[0] = new double[n - 1];
    Coef[1] = new double[n - 1];
    Coef[2] = new double[n - 1];
    Coef[3] = new double[n - 1];*/

    Coef = new double* [n - 1];
    for (int count = 0; count < n - 1; count++)
        Coef[count] = new double[4];


    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < n - 1; j++)
    {
        d[j] = (b[j + 1] + b[j] - 2 * delta[j]) / (h[j] * h[j]);
        c[j] = 2 * (delta[j] - b[j]) / h[j] - (b[j + 1] - delta[j]) / h[j];

        Coef[j][0] = a[j];
        Coef[j][1] = b[j];
        Coef[j][2] = c[j];
        Coef[j][3] = d[j];
    }

}
//*************************************************************************/
//Подсчет значения интерполянты в заданной точке
//*************************************************************************/
double Interpolate(double x)
{
    //double result;
    int i = 0;

    while (KnotArray[i].x < x)
        i++;
    i--;
    return Coef[i][0] + Coef[i][1] * (x - KnotArray[i].x) + Coef[i][2] * powf((x - KnotArray[i].x), 2) + Coef[i][3] * powf((x - KnotArray[i].x), 3);

}

//*************************************************************************/
//Загрузка данных
//*************************************************************************/
int Load_Data()
{
    printf("Input filename with data\n");
    char FileName[20];
    int i = 0;
    FILE* File;
    scanf_s("%s", &FileName, 20);
    if (!fopen_s(&File, FileName, "r"))
    {
        printf("file is opened\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%s: file doesn't exist\n", FileName);
        return -1;
    }
    double x, f, f2;
    fscanf_s(File, "%d", &n);
    KnotArray = new knot[n + 2];
    while (!feof(File))
    {
        fscanf_s(File, "%lf%lf%lf", &x, &f, &f2);
        KnotArray[i].Add(x, f, f2);
        i++;
        if (i == n)
            return 1;
    }
    fclose(File);
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    FILE* file_out;

    int N;//количество значений функции-интерполянты
    //double x = 0;
    printf("Input the number of interpolant values:\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &N);
    double* init = new double[N + 1];
    double* fun = new double[N + 1];
    double* fun_z = new double[N + 1];

    if (Load_Data() != -1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= N; i++)
        {
            init[i] = KnotArray[0].x + (KnotArray[n - 1].x - KnotArray[0].x) / N * i;

        }
        BuildSpline();
        fun[0] = KnotArray[0].f;
        fun_z[0] = KnotArray[0].f2;
        fun[N] = KnotArray[n - 1].f;
        fun_z[N] = KnotArray[n - 1].f2;
        for (int i = 1; i < N; i++)
        {
            fun[i] = Interpolate(init[i]);
            printf("i=%d f=%lf\n", i, fun[i]);
        }
        BuildSpline_z();
        for (int i = 1; i < N; i++)
        {
            fun_z[i] = Interpolate(init[i]);
        }
        if (fopen_s(&file_out, "D:\interp.dat", "wb"))
            printf("File could not be opened\n");
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= N; i++)
            {
                printf("x:  %lf\ty_interp:   %lf\tz_interp:   %lf\n", init[i], fun[i], fun_z[i]);
                fwrite(&init[i], sizeof(double), 1, file_out);
                fwrite(&fun[i], sizeof(double), 1, file_out);
                fwrite(&fun_z[i], sizeof(double), 1, file_out);
            }
        }
    }
    delete[] init;
    delete[] fun;
    delete[] fun_z;
    for (int count = 0; count < n - 1; count++)
        delete[] Coef[count];
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

[image: график исходных функций и интерполянт]

Answer (score 1):

Такое поведение наблюдается в случае равноястоящих друг от друга узлов интерполяции.
В этом случае всегда можно подобрать последовательность узлов либо полином при котором погрешности бесконечно растёт.

Этот эффект называется [феноменом рунге](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD_%D0%A0%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B5) и от его избавления, тоесть устремления ошибки к нулю на концах отрезка - обычно меняют узлы интерполяции, на [узлы чебышева](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%B7%D0%BB%D1%8B_%D0%A7%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%88%D1%91%D0%B2%D0%B0) например, которые гарантируют равномерно стремяющуюся к нулю погрешность интерполяции.

```
void chebishovNodes(unsigned a, unsigned b, unsigned n, std::vector<double>& nodes) {
    for (int i= 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        double x = (a + b)*0.5 + (b-a)*0.5*cos(PI*(2*i-1)/(2*n));
        nodes.push_back(x); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

У Вас действительно что-то не так с крайними полиномами.

Из кода мне навскидку не видно, какие заданы краевые условия.
Вот это что означает?

```
x3 = KnotArray[2].x - KnotArray[0].x;
xn = KnotArray[n - 1].x - KnotArray[n - 3].x;
....
f[0] = ((h[0] + 2 * x3) * h[1] * delta[0] + powf(h[0], 2) * delta[1]) / x3;
f[n - 1] = (powf(h[i - 1], 2) * delta[i - 2] + (2 * xn + h[i - 1]) * h[i - 2] * delta[i - 1]) / xn;
```

Можно задать нулевую вторую производную (свободные концы, натуральный сплайн) или определенную (в данном случае известную) первую производную - оба способа дают приемлемые результаты (второй чуть лучше) при использовании классической реализации, например, из [Numerical Recipes in C](https://www.cec.uchile.cl/cinetica/pcordero/MC_libros/NumericalRecipesinC.pdf) (глава 3.3)